# Updating JDO M-N relation in Datanucleus is not persisted

Tags: many-to-many, jdo, datanucleus

I have been exploring the Datanucleus framework and was trying some of the examples provided in the documentation. I got stuck in the M-N relation example using Sets. When I try to remove an object from the Set it is removed from the Set, but once I persist the container objects, the entry in the join table is not removed. This results in my container objects still holding the removed object.

I have a unit test that exposes the issue:

```
    @Test
public void testMNRelation() {
    final Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Product 1");
    product.setPrice(100);

    final Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setName("Product 2");
    product2.setPrice(130);

    final Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    supplier.setName("Supplier 1");

    Set<Supplier> suppliers = product.getSuppliers();
    suppliers.add(supplier);

    Set<Product> products = supplier.getProducts();
    products.add(product2);

    final PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("MyStore");
    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        pm.makePersistent(product);
        pm.makePersistent(product2);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }

    pm.close();

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Fetch from store (before removal)");
        Supplier s = pm.getObjectById(Supplier.class, supplier.getId());
        System.out.println("supplier name: " + s.getName());
        System.out.println("# products: " + s.getProducts().size());
        Product p = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, product.getId());
        System.out.println("product name: " + p.getName());
        System.out.println("# suppliers: " + p.getSuppliers().size());
        Product p2 = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, product2.getId());
        System.out.println("product name: " + p2.getName());
        System.out.println("# suppliers: " + p2.getSuppliers().size());
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }

    pm.close();

    Set<Product> updatedProducts = supplier.getProducts();
    updatedProducts.remove(product);
    Set<Supplier> updatedSuppliers = product.getSuppliers();
    updatedSuppliers.remove(supplier);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Before persist (after removal)");
    System.out.println("supplier name: " + supplier.getName());
    System.out.println("# products: " + supplier.getProducts().size());
    System.out.println("product name: " + product.getName());
    System.out.println("# suppliers: " + product.getSuppliers().size());
    System.out.println("product name: " + product2.getName());
    System.out.println("# suppliers: " + product2.getSuppliers().size());

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        pm.makePersistent(supplier);
        pm.makePersistent(product);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }

    pm.close();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("After persist");
    System.out.println("supplier name: " + supplier.getName());
    System.out.println("# products: " + supplier.getProducts().size());
    System.out.println("product name: " + product.getName());
    System.out.println("# suppliers: " + product.getSuppliers().size());
    System.out.println("product name: " + product2.getName());
    System.out.println("# suppliers: " + product2.getSuppliers().size());

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Fetch from store");
        Supplier s = pm.getObjectById(Supplier.class, supplier.getId());
        System.out.println("supplier name: " + s.getName());
        System.out.println("# products: " + s.getProducts().size());
        Product p = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, product.getId());
        System.out.println("product name: " + p.getName());
        System.out.println("# suppliers: " + p.getSuppliers().size());
        Product p2 = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, product2.getId());
        System.out.println("product name: " + p2.getName());
        System.out.println("# suppliers: " + p2.getSuppliers().size());
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }

    pm.close();
}
```

And the 2 types used in the example from http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/many_to_many.html

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class Supplier {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
private long id;

@Persistent
private String name;

@Persistent(mappedBy="suppliers")
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this.getId() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(o instanceof Supplier) {
        Supplier other = (Supplier) o;
        return this.getId() == other.getId();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Long.toString(this.getId()).hashCode();
}
}
```

And

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class Product {


@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
private long id;


@Persistent
private String name;

@Persistent
private double price;

@Persistent(table="PRODUCTS_SUPPLIERS")
@Join(column="PRODUCT_ID")
@Element(column="SUPPLIER_ID")
private Set<Supplier> suppliers = new HashSet<Supplier>();


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Set<Supplier> getSuppliers() {
    return suppliers;
}

public void setSuppliers(Set<Supplier> suppliers) {
    this.suppliers = suppliers;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(getId() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if(o instanceof Product) {
        Product other = (Product) o;
        return this.getId() == other.getId();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Long.toString(this.getId()).hashCode();
}

}
```

Now, in the console I get

```
Fetch from store (before removal)
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 2
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 1
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

Before persist (after removal)
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 0
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

After persist
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 1
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

Fetch from store
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 1
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1
```

I would expect something like

```
Fetch from store (before removal)
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 2
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 1
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

Before persist (after removal)
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 0
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

After persist
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 0
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1

Fetch from store
supplier name: Supplier 1
# products: 1
product name: Product 1
# suppliers: 0
product name: Product 2
# suppliers: 1
```

My persistence.xml includes:

```
<property name="datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.attachSameDatastore" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.CopyOnAttach" value="false" />
<property name="datanucleus.cache.collections.lazy" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.manageRelationships" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.manageRelationshipsChecks" value="true" />
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Your persistence code is weird. You do "product.getSuppliers().add()" and then call product.setSuppliers() which is pointless (the aupplier is already in the set of suppliers at that point). You haven't set both sides of the relations either, adding a product to one set of suppliers and a different supplier to a product. Inconsistent. I'm sure the log would tell you what was persisted and what wasn't

Comment: ok, I removed the product.setSupplier and supplier.setProduct invocations - you are right, they are pointless. The reason why I set one product on the supplier and the supplier on the other product was to test the managed relations. It works perfectly when adding data to the object graph - so I do not have to add objects on both sides of the many-to-many relation. The question is regarding the second part, where I remove one of the relations (supplier not longer supply product 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution to the issue. The issue seems to relate to my persistence settings. I changed the settings to

```
<property name="datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.attachSameDatastore" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.CopyOnAttach" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.cache.collections.lazy" value="true" />
<property name="datanucleus.manageRelationships" value="false" />
<property name="datanucleus.manageRelationshipsChecks" value="false" />
<property name="datanucleus.persistenceByReachabilityAtCommit" value="false" />
```

as I now handle both sides of the relation in my implementation.

Furthermore I implemented a Factory to simplify my test

```
public class Factory {

  private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = get();

  private static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
    return JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("MyStore");
  }

  public static Product buildProduct(String name, double price) {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName(name);
    product.setPrice(price);
    save(product);
    return product;
  }

  public static Supplier buildSupplier(String name) {
    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    supplier.setName(name);
    save(supplier);
    return supplier;
  }

  public static void addRelation(final Supplier supplier, final Product product) {
    product.getSuppliers().add(supplier);
    supplier.getProducts().add(product);
    save(product, supplier);
  }

  public static void removeRelation(Supplier supplier, Product product) {
    product.getSuppliers().remove(supplier);
    supplier.getProducts().remove(product);
    save(product, supplier);
  }

  public static Product loadProduct(long id) {
    return (Product) load(Product.class, id);
  }

  public static Supplier loadSupplier(long id) {
    return (Supplier) load(Supplier.class, id);
  }

  private static void save(final Object... objects) {
    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
      tx.begin();
      pm.makePersistentAll(objects);
      tx.commit();
    } finally {
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
      }
    }
    pm.close();
  }

  private static Object load(Class<?> clazz, long id) {
    final Object[] result = new Object[1];
    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
      tx.begin();
      result[0] = pm.getObjectById(clazz, id);
      tx.commit();
    } finally {
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
      }
    }
    pm.close();
    if (result[0] == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException(clazz.getSimpleName() + " with id=" + id + " cannot be found");
    }
    return result[0];
  }
}
```

So the test is simply expressed as

```
@Test
public void testFactoryApproach() {
    Product p1 = Factory.buildProduct("product1", 50);
    Product p2 = Factory.buildProduct("product2", 70);
    Supplier s1 = Factory.buildSupplier("Supplier1");

    System.out.println("Initial:");
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println();

    Factory.addRelation(s1, p1);
    Factory.addRelation(s1, p2);

    System.out.println("Relations after add:");
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println();

    Factory.removeRelation(s1, p1);

    System.out.println("Relations after remove:");
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Relations after load:");
    System.out.println(Factory.loadProduct(p1.getId()));
    System.out.println(Factory.loadProduct(p2.getId()));
    System.out.println(Factory.loadSupplier(s1.getId()));
}
```

Which result in the following output

```
Initial:
Product:11 (product1) - # suppliers = 0 []
Product:12 (product2) - # suppliers = 0 []
Supplier:11 (Supplier1) - # products = 0 []

Relations after add:
Product:11 (product1) - # suppliers = 1 [11:Supplier1]
Product:12 (product2) - # suppliers = 1 [11:Supplier1]
Supplier:11 (Supplier1) - # products = 2 [11:product1, 12:product2]

Relations after remove:
Product:11 (product1) - # suppliers = 0 []
Product:12 (product2) - # suppliers = 1 [11:Supplier1]
Supplier:11 (Supplier1) - # products = 1 [12:product2]

Relations after load:
Product:11 (product1) - # suppliers = 0 []
Product:12 (product2) - # suppliers = 1 [11:Supplier1]
Supplier:11 (Supplier1) - # products = 1 [12:product2]
```